# How to fix "QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread" when closing a pyqt gui started in another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread, qtimer

I am developping a Python GUI application with pyqt. I need to keep the python console responsive while using the GUI, so my GUI is started in a another thread, in this way :

```py
class AppThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):

        from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        if app is None:
           app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

        from mywindow import MyWindow # The code of the window is in another python script
        gui = MyWindow()
        gui.show()
        app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    myapp = AppThread()
```

The GUI is working well, but when I close it, I get the following error :

```py
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Of course, I don't get this error if I run directly the code :

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

from mywindow import MyWindow # The code of the window is in another python script
gui = MyWindow()
gui.show()
app.exec_()
```

My question is then how to get rid of this error when instantiating a gui in a thread that is not the main one ?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Qt does not support gui operations of any kind outside the main thread.

Comment: @ekhumoro how to keep the command line working when using the gui then ?

Comment: @qcha Put it in the background (i.e. `python myapp.py &`, or whatever the syntax is on your platform). Or just open another console.